# Importing .csv files made from R:write.csv - some values are <Null>

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, r, null

When i make a data frame in R, e.g. like this:

```
x <- data.frame(sum=c(0.00, 0.00, 1363.31, 27663.58, 27663.58), ID=1:5)
```

I can save it with write.csv

```
write.csv(x, "x.csv")
```

But when i open the x.csv file in arcmap it reads the three last numbers in x$sum as < Null >. Why is this, and is there a way to ensure that ArcMap reads numbers correctly?

A workaround is to open it in excel and save it as a worksheet, but there has to be an easier way.

I dont think its the decimal separator - when I open it in notebook it looks like this:

"","sum","ID"
"1",0,1
"2",0,2
"3",1363.31,3
"4",27663.58,4
"5",27663.58,5

Answer (score 1):

It isn't an `R` issue, is how your PC interprets decimal symbol. If you have a different decimal symbol than `.`, you'll get `NULL` value in ArcMap:

[image: null]

Go to `Control Panel/Regional and Language Options/Format tab` and change decimal separator. An useful configuration is:

- Decimal symbol: `.`
- Digit grouping symbol: `,`
- List separator: `,`

After apply configuration, open again ArcMap and import `.csv` again, you'll get:

[image]

Comment: My settings were already as you suggest. So its not that. Is there a  decimal separator option in ArcMap?

Comment: No, ArcMap takes local regional and language settings. Try changing language to "English (United States)", then apply and restart ArcMap.

Comment: I changed the language, but its still not working. I have started creating the shapefiles in R instead, but would be nice to be able to do both without having to open the file in excel and and saving it as a worksheet.